# Accessing different region s3 bucket from an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have assigned a role with the following policy to my ec2 instance running on `us-west-2` region -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and trying to access a bucket from `ap-southeast-1` region. The problem is every `aws s3` operations are timing out. I have also tried specifying region in the command `--region ap-southeast-1`.

From the documentation, I found this pointer -

> Endpoints are supported within the same region only. You cannot create
>   an endpoint between a VPC and a service in a different region.

So, what is the process to access bucket from a different region using aws-cli or boto client from the instance?

Comment: First, your instance must be able to access the internet.

Comment: Yes, egress is set to access all...

Comment: Are you able to do a `curl` or `wget` to google.com ?

Comment: @mootmoot, just figured out my instance didn't have any public ip, neither behind a NAT.. Therefore, were not able to access public internet and s3 bucket from a different region. Though accessing public internet is not my requirement, but I got an idea how to solve the bucket access issue. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, to access bucket from a different region, the instance also needs access to the public internet. Therefore, the instance needs to have a public ip or it has to be behind a NAT.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not necessary to specify the region of the bucket in order to access to it, you can check some boto3 examples from here:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I tried this already. Works fine for the same region, but getting connection timeout for different region bucket. 

I do agree with you that specifying bucket is not mandatory thing, it just saves additional API call to get the bucket location

Comment: Check out this link [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223524) it seems to be the same problem and it is fixed using --region us-west-2 in the CLI

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure you've given the above permission to the correct User or Role.

Run the command;

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

You may think the EC2 instance is using credentials you've set when it may be using an IAM role.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. It's a nice debugging trick. But seems like it was a different issue. Apparently, instance didn't have access to the public internet.